# Logs not appearing in Graylog

Tags: logging, quarkus, gelf, graylog3

I made an application yesterday and wanted to log the messages in Graylog and for that, I followed the instructions of https://quarkus.io/guides/centralized-log-management, installed a Graylog instance on a remote server and configured my application.

```
#### Graylog logging
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.enabled=true
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.host=my_remote_server
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.filter-stack-trace=true
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.level=ALL
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.include-full-mdc=true
```

Here is what the code looks like

```
@POST
@Produces(TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public TemplateInstance perform(@Form final SearchRequest request) {
    LOGGER.debug(String.format("[%s] Calling search page", applicationName));
    final String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    LOGGER.debug(format("{%s]  -> Searching for lawyers with data '%s'", applicationName, requestId, request));
    final Query query = searchQueryBuilder.createSearchHibernateQuery(request);
    List< MedicalDoctor> medicalDoctors = (List< MedicalDoctor>) query.getResultList();
    LOGGER.debug(format("[%s] %s -> Searching for lawyers with data '%s' : count %d -> %s", applicationName, requestId, request, medicalDoctors.size(), medicalDoctors));
    return main().data("medicalDoctors", medicalDoctors).data("request", request);
}
```

As a logger, I'm using

```
private static final org.jboss.logging.Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MenuPages.class);
```

I have no idea why but in Graylog I can only see the logs from the Quarkus startup and none coming from my application (it is not the only method that is supposed to be logging). I tried to change the log message from DEBUG to INFO but to no avail.

Anybody has a clue what is going on for what I misconfigured somewhere?

Thanks for the help,

D.

Comment: Can you try changing your log levels to INFO to check that there is no issue with minimum log level somewhere ?

Comment: I already changed it from ALL to DEBUG and to INFO but to no avail.

Comment: I made a clean slate and rewrote everything, put the log level to INFO in the properties file and in the code and it worked. Thanks for the tip.

I would have thought that with "ALL" as log level, it should have definitively worked.

Comment: Yes, it should have work. This seems to be a bug.

Comment: @loicmathieu should I open a bug for it?

Comment: Yes please, with a reproducer if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the log level to INFO in

```
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.level=INFO
```

and using debug.info in the code meaning

```
LOGGER.info(format("%s]  -> Searching for lawyers with data '%s'", applicationName, requestId, request));
```

did the trick. Merci Loic